# Jackson deserialize into synesthetic class

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have an object with custom getters that implement business logic based on constructor arguments, eg.

```
class Test {
    private int number;
    Test(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public boolean isEven() {
        return number % 2 == 0;
    }
}
```

which is serialised as `{"even": true}`

I would like to deserialize this object such that a proxy is created that returns isEven() based on the serialized value. Is something like this possible using jackson?

Comment: Why not deserialize it to a `java.util.Map` and just read `map.get("even")`? If you want to call the `isEven` method, you'd have to compile that, which may also justify simply writing a class to deserialize that JSON as.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I have a complex object model and this model is used in other parts of the code, therefore it's imperative to keep the object types unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, this is possible using property-based static `@JsonCreator` method:

```
public class Test {
    private int number;
    ...

        @JsonCreator
        public static Test fromJson(@JsonProperty("even") Boolean isEven) {
            return new Test(isEven ? 2 : 1);
        }
}
```

Comment: This above example was a toy example, in my real use case scenario I would not be able to apply such a reverse 'hack' (`isEven ? 2 : 1`).

Comment: what this example demonstrates is how you can get Jackson to call a method with input json and translate it into ctor arguments